# Is there an official way to create discrete-valued range widget in GTK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, gobject

From what I can see, the behavior any `Range`-based widget is  defined by an `Adjustements` one.

Since there seems to be no official way to restrict the range to a few discrete values, I have tried a lots of ways  to actually reset the values.

What works, **but is not optimal**, is simply to take the current value and determine which valid discrete value is the nearest from that continuous value and use that instead.

But what I would like is to visually freeze the slider to its current position until the user grabs it far enough and then change its value at once to the next valid value.

I want the user to understand and feel that these are discrete values. The problem with my working solution above is that the 3 users who tested the program told me that I should put more figures in the number I displayed, thinking the change was continuous.

NB: by "official", I mean either a "hidden" option or subclass of the `Adjustements` class if at all available. If not, any way that is reasonably efficient to achieve such a requirement (i.e. that don't use 50% of CPU for a simple slider!). In particular, I am **not asking** for the "ultimate best way" to do this.

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScale.html#gtk-scale-add-mark) do what you need? I haven't used it myself, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, this is a good suggestion, but it mixes presentation and behavior which is not good. Imagine a slider ranging from 0 to 100 with one such tick for each integer value: that would be ugly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you can just override the `change-value` signal:

```
class DiscreteScale(Gtk.Scale):
    def __init__(self, values, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        values.sort()
        self.values = values
        
        adjustment = self.get_adjustment()
        adjustment.set_lower(values[0])
        adjustment.set_upper(values[-1])
        
        self.__changed_value_id = self.connect('change-value', self.__change_value)
    
    def __change_value(self, scale, scroll_type, value):
        # find the closest valid value
        value = self.__closest_value(value)
        # emit a new signal with the new value
        self.handler_block(self.__changed_value_id)
        self.emit('change-value', scroll_type, value)
        self.handler_unblock(self.__changed_value_id)
        return True #prevent the signal from escalating
    
    def __closest_value(self, value):
        return min(self.values, key=lambda v:abs(value-v))
```

A little demo:

```
w = Gtk.Window()
s = DiscreteScale([0, 1, 5, 20, 22])
w.add(s)
w.set_size_request(500, 50)

w.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify the discrete valued interval you were looking for, but GtkRange (and thus GtkScale) supports rounding:

```
scale_widget.set_round_digits(1)
scale_widget.set_digits(1)
```

I suspect this is the solution for discrete valued GtkScale that many users are looking for.

https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkrange.html#method-gtkrange--set-round-digits
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRange.html#gtk-range-set-round-digits